# при добавлении tooltip расширяется div

Tags: html, css, reactjs

```js
renderChatItemDescription = () => {
  const {chat = {}, sessionUser = {}, withTooltip} = this.props;
  const {lastMessage = {}} = chat;
  const {isSystemMessage, creatorId} = lastMessage;

  return(
   <div className="new-chat-list-item__body-area__second-line">
    {this.renderPreDiscription()}
    <ElipsedText
     withTooltip
     className={`new-chat-list-item__body-area__second-line__text ${isSystemMessage ? 'new-chat-list-item__system-message' : ''}`}
     offset={0}
     tooltipOffset={110}
     titleStyles={{
      fontWeight: 400,
      background: '#505050',
      wordBreak: 'break-all',
      maxWidth: 200
     }}

     style={{
       paddingTop: sessionUser.id === creatorId ? '2px' : undefined,
      // width: 'calc(100% - 30%)'
     }}
    >
     {lastMessage.text}
    </ElipsedText>
   </div>
  )
 };
```

```css
.new-chat-list-item__body-area__second-line {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    /*justify-content: center;*/
}

.new-chat-list-item__body-area__first-line__text {
    color: black;
    font-size: 14px;
    max-width: 100%;
}

.new-chat-list-item__body-area__second-line__text-head {
    color: rgb(74, 66, 147);
    font-size: 12px;
    margin-right: 5px;
}

.new-chat-list-item__body-area__second-line__text {
    color: grey;
    font-size: 12px;
    min-width: 0;
    flex: 1;
    white-space: nowrap;
    /*display:flex;*/
    /*width: 100%;*/
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]
есть tooltip и при его добавлении div становится по ширине длиннее чем нужно, когда убираю то все нормально и появляются ... если текст не влезает, когда добавляю они исчезают и в отладчике показано что текст уходит за пределы.
1) с тултипом
2) без тултипа.
Шапка кстати тоже с тултипом и там нормально текст режется, почему тут так - не могу разобраться

Собственно добавил пикчи, хз

Comment: Мне тут на днях пришлось работать со старым кодом. Его кто-то когда-то написал и там тоже были тултипы. Когда они появлялись, вёрстка ползла. Починилось исправлением позиционирования с относительного на абсолютное. Может и у тебя та же беда.

Comment: Ну как бы код приложите?